# Python multiprocessing with numpy array and SAT solver

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've looked around the forum and can't seem to find anything that helps.  I'm trying to parallelize some processes but cannot seem to get it to work.

```
from multiprocessing import *
from numpy import *

x=array([1,2,3,4,5])

def SATSolver(args):
    #many_calculations
    return result

def main(arg):
    new_args=append(x,arg)
    return SATSolver(new_args)

y=array([8,9,10,11])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool=Pool()
    results=pool.map(main,y)
    print(results)
```

The SATSolver function is where the bulk of the work happens.  Basically, I have an array x and a second array y.  I want to add append each value in y to x individually, and then run this new set through my SATSolver function.  I would like to use the multiprocessing module so this can run in parallel.

Whenever I try and run this, I don't get an error, but a new interactive window pops up and says "Could not load the file from *filepath*\-c.  Do you want to create a new file?"

Everything works perfectly when it's run without multiprocessing.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run the file form the command line?

Comment: Seems to run without errors when I run from command line.  However, it seems like everything is being run 4 times.  Instead of just allowing parallel processes for the one function it is running everything multiple times, whether it's within the 'main(arg)' or not.